# How to do a query on custom taxonomies that is uncategorised?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query

I have a custom taxonomy and I wish to do a query for all custom posts who has no value assigned for that taxonomy (i.e. uncategorised).

This is what I have so far:

```
  $uncatQuery = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'         =>  'course',
                'tax_query' => array (
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'course_category',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => '',
                    )
                )
            ) );
```

However this does not work.

Please help!

NOTE: I manage to get it to work by creating a query to get all tax ids and then use a NOT IN operator, but that requires an additional query.

Comment: Do you have an 'Uncategorized' category?  I believe you should.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but how would I make it so when I create a course it will be default as this "uncategorized" course. The whole reason I'm doing this is so I can list all the courses my client forgot to put a category to (or not yet decided).

Comment: Did you try using the 'operator' parameter? You'll probably have to put all existing terms in 'terms'. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it worked like I said in my question. However it required an additional query: $categoryIds = get_terms('course-categories'). I was wondering if it was possible to do it more quickly using just the WP_QUERY.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with custom taxonomies, but isn't an uncategorized term automatically generated?

Comment: Sorry about repeating the already tried operator, Yahya. It should be easy, when saving a cpt instance, to check for terms and if none are found, assign it to uncategorized.

Comment: whats a cpt instance? And I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean when you create a post of type 'course'. On save, check for terms and if none are found, assign it to uncategorized.

Comment: Nice idea. But think I'll leave that as a VERY last resort. I prefer the 2 queries method though as its simpler to code.

Comment: There isn't a way to do it with WP_Query that doesn't involve either getting all term IDs first (as you mention), or modifying the SQL directly via filters. From a performance perspective the impact of the extra query is negligible, doing it with a single query just rolls the extra query into a single statement, but doesn't really reduce the amount of work the database is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for all the helpful comments. It turns out there is no way to do this using WP_QUERY alone.

The best way I can think of is to do it is like so:

```
$taxIds = get_terms($options['post-types'][$this->current_post_type->name], array(
                'fields'        => 'ids',
            ));
            $uncategorisedQuery = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'         =>  $postType,
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'tax_query' => array (
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomyType,
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $taxIds,
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                )
            ) );
```

Although @shanbp had a nice idea of creating a "Uncategorised" taxonomy and automatically applying it to each post on creation if no taxonomy is selected.